# ConfigurationManager.GetSection(sectionName) returns null while performing unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, nunit, configurationmanager

I have a unit tests project with it's own `app.config` file, which is a mock of a real configuration file defined by target project being tested. This mock file is loaded and processed by unit test code (not by target project), and it works properly if I run only tests within only this one test project.

```
ConfigurationManager.GetSection(sectionName)
```

However, if I run tests from several test projects, and other test projects are performed prior to relevant project, the above statement returns `null`. If discussed test project is performed as first, there is no problem with loading configuration file.

How can I fix loading of configuration file in unit test to work correctly?

Comment: I face Similar issue with test project and Sqlite each time I run the test project a new Sqlite database get created and that's not happening with the main project , so in order to test I had to create normal console application Instead of test project.


I don't know if this information help or not some cases test project just not that good Especially when it comes to dealing with external resources What makes it even more bizarre that I face this issue with visual 2010 but when I upgrade to 2012 everything work just fine !!!

Comment: i think you can only have one active config file and the frst one is the one used for all projects, when you have normal projects this is done but in test project it's not, so copy (merge) the web config to all projects and see if it works.

Comment: So you have an app.config in one unit test project, and other unit test projects are dependent on that app.config? That's not very sustainable. I'd suggest either replicating that mock app.config to each test project or going with the mock suggestion of @Ouarzy below. It also depends on what you are testing: that ConfigurationManager.GetSection() call or something else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is not ConfigurationManager.GetSection(sectionName) returns null, it is how can I test some code containing ConfigurationManager.GetSection(sectionName)?

And the answer is: wrap it, inject it, then for your test mock it.

You have several examples of pepole facing the same issue:

- http://chrisondotnet.com/2011/05/configurationmanager-wrapper-for-unit-testing/
- http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/03/03/unit-testable-configuration-manager.aspx

(The second one is much more detailed, still the idea is the same).

Anyway, this is quite logical that you cannot use information from app.config in a unit test, as an app.config is contextual for the whole application, when it is required to write test absolutely independant. If you use directly an app.config value, then you have non logical coupling.

Comment: This is all well and good, but what about if what you're trying to test is the code that touches the configuration manager?  I'm in that situation and all the suggestions I find say I should just abstract the ConfigurationManager out of my tests but if I do that then there's nothing to test.

Comment: If you have nothing to test when you abstract the ConfigurationManager, it suggests to me that you need a refactoring to have a better responsability segregation.

Comment: How much more segregated can you get than a class whose sole purpose to fetch or change values using the ConfigurationManager, implementing an interface that gets and sets configuration values?

Comment: I guess this discussion could be long without example :) If you wish contact me on ouarzy'at'free.fr and share some code via GitHub so we may discuss it

Answer (score 2):

Facing the same issue this solved it:
`app.config` should be picked up inside a unit test if it's `Copy to Output Directory` property set to `Copy if newer` or if you add the DeploymentItem attribute `[DeploymentItem("your.config")]`.

More detailed description:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e520735-8ced-4092-b681-38b69e0db534/unit-test-configuration#32998bf4-5a76-4083-99da-42f0c3a91559

similar question: [MSTest and app.config issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811778/mstest-and-app-config-issue)

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is either it could not find the file in test working directory or file itself failed to load.

I have solved this problem by explicitly loading configuration file with name. In your case you can try same.

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"d:\test\test.config";
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the test project post build command line, but remember to build the project if there are changes:

```
copy /Y "$(SolutionDir)$(SolutionName)\App.Debug.config" "$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName)$(TargetExt).config"
```