# Modify Custom Section in App.config

Tags: c#, configuration

I have the following custom section in my config file:

```
<TestSettings>
    <EmailAddress></EmailAddress>
</TestSettings>
```

I tried to modify this section on runtime with the following method:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var testSettings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("TestSettings") as NameValueCollection;

if (testSettings != null)
{
    testSettings["EmailAddress"] = emailAddress;
    config.Save();
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("TestSettings");
}
```

But the GetSection method returns null.
What is the simplest way to solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you running this from a test dll?

Comment: You `OpenExeConfiguration` and store that in `config`, then you don't use `config` to try and get the "TestSettings"?

Comment: Yes. I want to modify the App.config file for my unit tests.

Answer (score -1):

So you running this from a *test assembly*. Re-read the method name:

`ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration`

Do you see it?

> ConfigurationManager.Open**Exe**Configuration

For a solution have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18607359/706456).