# MSTest fails: Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's .config file

Tags: c#, unit-testing, log4net, mstest

This is my setup:

```
/
solution.sln
Core/
    Core.csproj
web/
    web.csproj
    Web.config
Test/
    Test.csproj
    App.config
build/
    _PublishedWebsites/web/etc...
    test.dll
    test.dll.config
    Core.dll
    log4net.dll
```

I wrote Unit Tests in the `Test` project that test the functionality of the `Core` project. All of the projects use log4net, all of them are configured using the respective `App.config` or `Web.config` files using

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

in their `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

The projects are built using NAnt into a `build` directory.

When I run the Unit Tests from Visual Studio (2010 Professional), everything works fine.

But when I try to execute MSTest directly

```
MSTest.exe /resultsfile:TestResults.trx /noisolation /testcontainer:build\test.dll
```

All test cases fail with the following error:

```
log4net:ERROR Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's .config file
```

This confuses me, because the `test.dll.config` file most definitely contains the `log4net` configuration section.

The folder created by MSTest also **contains the config file**:

```
/flopes_MyMachine 2015-10-08 08_48_59/Out/
    Core.dll
    test.dll
    test.dll.config
    log4net.dll
```

It appears to me that maybe `MSTest` is using a wrong configuration file or doesnt find the configuration file of the `test.dll`? Does that even make sense? Is there a way to tell MSTest which config file to use?

I did a small test output to see what configuration file is loaded, and it added even more mystery, because apparently the configuration file that was loaded is:

```
D:\Programme\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe.Config
```

How is this possible? Why does MSTest not just load the configuration file that **is right beside** the `test.dll`? How does this make sense?

Comment: Does it change if you run mstest from within the build-folder? (ie so that working directory is different)

Comment: @flindeberg Nop, same config file is loaded, no matter what working dir.

Comment: Is it possible you can create a minimal working example which I can have a look at? I cannot recreate your scenario =/ (given that the .config is part of the deployment as a deployment item)

Comment: @flindeberg Well... I can't either apparently. I tried creating a MWE for two hours now, but somehow it works when I start from scratch. Still this is information; it means that something else besides what I listed here must be causing the problem...

Comment: @flindeberg Okay, as soon as I remove the `noisolation` parameter from the MSTest call, it 1. uses the correct configuration file and 2. runs the tests as normal... Can't figure out how the isolation should actually work though

Comment: Weird, `noisolation` basically controls the creation of separate sandboxes for the test-instances, but maybe the creation of separate processes is needed to use a "dynamic" and non-hardcoded config for ms-test.

Comment: @flindeberg Well it seems this is also the answer... It all boils down to `/noisolation`. Do you want to update your answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have a look at this question and answer: [MSTest.exe not finding app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484800/mstest-exe-not-finding-app-config)

Which states that you should create a test run configuration which includes the .config as a deployment item.

Also check if the config being used is the correct one; ways of finding active config-file:

```
// Get the user-config:
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).FilePath

// Simple approach
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile? Is it the correct .config
```

Checking a couple of things with @florianpeschka led us to believe that the problem is the `noisolation`-flag. And that is a bit weird, since `noisolation` basically controls the creation of separate sandboxes for the test-instances, but maybe the creation of separate processes is needed to use a "dynamic" and non-hardcoded config for ms-test.

So in short, do not use the `noisolation`-flag and everything works.

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the underlying problem. The `config` file is properly deployed into the `TestResults/Out/` folder, see my question. The file is there, it's just somehow not picked up by MSTest...

Comment: What is `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile`? Is it the correct `.config`-file?

Comment: How should I find that out? Can I debug into the MSTestExecution?

Comment: Maybe remove log4net (so it runs) and write the variable to file?

Comment: Well that's interesting... I added the output to my question.