# How correctly create class from message

Tags: c#, grpc

How correctly create class from other with structure:

```
message ResultDto {
    bool Result = 1;
    repeated string Errors = 2;
    ResultModuleDto Module = 3;
}
```

from

```
message ResultModuleDto {
   string Name = 1;
   string Path = 2;
   repeated SectionCollectionDto SectionCollection = 3;
}

message SectionCollectionDto {
    string Name = 1;
    string Path = 2;
    repeated HelpFileDto Files = 3;
}

message HelpFileDto {
    string Name = 1;
    string Path = 2;
}
```

I try create like a class `var module = new ResultModuleDto { Name = moduleDto.Name, Path = moduleDto.Path };`

But I catch a System.Memory exeption.

Comment: there's nothing unusual about the proto shown; can you please give the full exception message and ideally stack-trace? that *should* work fine. Also: what tools are you using to get a C# model from the proto? (there are at least 2 that I can think of, so: it matters). Even better would be a runnable example that shows what you're doing here - again, the schema shown is perfectly fine and normal, so it doesn't help with context.

Comment: Message:
    Test method Help.Servers.Tests.UnitTest1.StudyRepositoryService_A3s threw an exception:
    System.TypeInitializationException: An initializer of type "ResultDto" threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly "System.Memory, Version = 4.0.1.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" or one of its dependencies. Found assembly manifest definition does not match assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).

Comment: Stack trace:
    FieldCodec.ForString (UInt32 tag, String defaultValue)
    FieldCodec.ForString (UInt32 tag) line 56
    ResultDto.cctor () line 101
    --- End of the internal exception stack trace ---
    ResultDto.ctor ()
    HelpServiceGrpc.GetAllModules (ModuleDto moduleDto, ServerCallContext context) line 32
    <StudyRepositoryService_A3s> d__0.MoveNext () line 25
    --- End of the stack trace from the previous location where the

Comment: exception was thrown ---
    TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (Task task)
    TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (Task task)
    ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety (Action action)

Answer (score 1):

From the extended message info, it sounds like you're using .NET Framework 4.something; the good news is: this isn't a huge problem, although I do *strongly suggest* using .NET Core 3.1 or .NET 5 if at all possible. Then the problem *just goes away*, plus you'll be using a **much** better platform.

What you're seeing is the result of a missing and necessary "assembly binding redirect", due to some really complex internal .NET Framework packaging details, and **a known bug in tooling** that means that build *does not auto-generate* the required assembly binding redirects (it is meant to, it is simply: a bug).

This means that you need to add the binding redirect manually in your application (i.e. the executable or web app). This is covered in a *lot more detail here*: https://nickcraver.com/blog/2020/02/11/binding-redirects/ - but ultimately just means tweaking your `app.config`/`web.config` file to include a section much like the example from the post - in this case `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`, but the same concept applies to `System.Memory` (another "known offender"), i.e.

```xml
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.6.0" newVersion="4.0.6.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <!-- ...and maybe some more... -->
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but i call this method in MSTest testing class. And i hav't app.config.

Comment: @AlexejDrosdov https://stackoverflow.com/a/3424555/23354