# Missing app.config file?

Tags: vb.net

I just inherited a VB.Net application that gets a SQL connection string like this:

```
Dim m_GMSConnString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("connString")
```

But there's no app.config file in the solution/project. So where is it reading from?

EDIT: If this is a DLL project and the DLL is then referenced by a website project, will the DLL read from the web.config of the website project? That's the only explanation I can come up with.

Comment: What does Console.Out.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile); dump out ?

Comment: This is a DLL project. Where would I even put that in the code?

Comment: Of course it gets configuration from the web.config file :) All the included dlls in web projects are sharing the same config.

Comment: But this is a separate project and not part of the website project. The dll is just added as a reference to the website project. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you have schema like \web.config \bin\ConnectionString.dll and \bin\Web.dll and the ConnectionString.dll will ask for app settings, it will fetch the app settings from web.config

Answer (score 1):

> EDIT: If this is a DLL project and the DLL is then referenced by a
>   website project, will the DLL read from the web.config of the website
>   project? That's the only explanation I can come up with.

From my experience (and it is confirmed here [Why wont my application read my MyApplication.dll.config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836386/why-wont-my-application-read-my-myapplication-dll-config-file)) answer is yes, the code will only read the app.config of the main project (or web.config in your case).

But the answer also provides link that show how to use multiple config file. I think you can tell your program to read some part from external file (your dll.config file in your case).

Answer (score 0):

if I remember correct, there is a config file with the same name as the exe file but add the extention of .config, such as yourprog.exe.config

Comment: This is a DLL project if that matters. The file you mention doesn't exist.

Comment: app.config in the main (exe) project? if you compile the program, it generates the config file as same as the exe file name

Comment: AGAIN... it's not an EXE, it's a DLL. And no, when I build there is no config file generated.