# Use common Web.config/App.config parts

Tags: .net

Let's imagine I have 40 projects: 20 with implementation and 20 with tests. Some of implementation modules (those which are applications but not libraries) have App.config/Web.config and all test projects have App.config (for NUnit).

For some projects (primarily for test projects) I would like to use the same config file without copy+pasting. For some other projects I would like to have only some sections being the same (for example, connection strings).

Are there any ways to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend linking sections in your config file(s) to shared external files, like this: [Link config file sections](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/06/Keep-your-config-clean-with-external-config-files.aspx)
Also look at this question: [How to manage .NET app.config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89245/how-do-you-manage-net-app-config-files-for-large-applications)