# How to export one MEF plugin multiple times, depending on app.config?

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I am building a simple MEF application. What I want to achieve is building one plugin, which can be registered multiple times in the same composing application. The registration of the plugin should be dependent on a setting from the configfile of the plugin, but I am not able to do this.

[edit]

My server, which has the CompositionContainer, needs to communicate with 6 different targets (ie Traffic Light Controllers). For every target, I want to add a plugin. The plugin logic is the same, so I want to maintain only 1 plugin. Every target has its own webaddress to communicate (and some other configuration items), I want those to be in (separate) configfiles.

What I tried is putting the plugins in subdirectories and going recursively through those directories to add the plugins in the catalog. This doesn't work however. The second plugin found in the subdirs will be imported, but this one is targeting the first plugin. When looping through the container FASTAdapters, all parts seem to equal to the first.

```
private void Compose()
{
    var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
    string sDir = AppSettingsUtil.GetString("FASTAdaptersLocation", @"./Plugins");
    foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
    {
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(d));
    }
    var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
    container.ComposeParts(this);
}
```

I don't know if I can also use the ExportMetadata attribute. It seems that ExportMetadata attributes have to be hardcoded, but I want the attribute being read from the config file if possible.

[/edit]

My goal is to have 6 ControllerAdapters, each targeting a different controller (read: communicating with a different webserver). The logic in the 6 ControllerAdapters is equal.

I thought copying the ClassLibrary (for example to 1.dll, 2.dll and so on) and adding the configfiles (1.dll.config and so on) should do the trick, but no.

When composing, I get multiple instances `typeof(FAST.DevIS.ControllerAdapter)` in the container, but I don't know how to get further.

Do I need to do something with MetaData in the export?

The importing server

```
[ImportMany]
public IEnumerable<IFASTAdapter> FASTAdapters { get; set; }

private void Compose()
{
    var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
    catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(AppSettingsUtil.GetString("FASTAdaptersLocation", Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ControllerServer)).Location))));
    var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
    container.ComposeParts(this);
}
```

The plugin

```
namespace FAST.DevIS.ControllerAdapter
{
   [Export (typeof(IFASTAdapter))]
   public class ControllerAdapter : IFASTAdapter
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

The interface

```
namespace FAST.Common.FastAdapter
{
    public interface IFASTAdapter
    {
        /// Parse plan parameters
        /// 
        //Activator
        bool ParsePlan(PlansContainer plan);
        bool ActivatePlan();
        void Configure(string config);
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't really clear what you want. From your question body, you say that you get multiple versions in the container but you don't know how to get further. So, is the only problem that you need to control the export from the app.config? Someone will be more likely to help you if you are very explicit with what you need.

Comment: Tried to make clear what my goal is.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. You should be able to make use of the `InheritedExport` attribute on your interface. That way you can remove the `Export` attributes from classes. When you then use `ImportMany`, it will bring back each class that implements `IFASTAdapter`. http://blogs.geniuscode.net/JeremiahRedekop/?p=235

Comment: Thanks, going to try that!

Comment: Strange enough this doesn't work. Also in this case I get a reference to the same assembly.

Comment: http://yfrog.com/eb51kp Here you can see that the second part in the catalog is composed from the directory O020, but it references the assembly in O010. This is the same behaviour as without the InheritedExport attribute...

Comment: @Cornelis, if the logic in each adapter is the same, why don't you just have a single config file which designates the (webserver) targets?  On _Startup_ and On _Config Changed_, recreate each `ControllerAdapter` from the configured targets.  (It doesn't seem like you even need MEF.)

Comment: @jberger Thanks for the suggestion. Meanwhile I took another approach: I have built six MEF plugins, only differing in metadata, based on a baseclass implementing the logic and also implementing the IFASTAdapter interface. I opted for MEF to be able to implement a different logic easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be more a problem with how you are using assemblies than with the MEF solution.

You say:

> The logic in the 6 ControllerAdapters is equal.

So is it the same DLL just copied 6 times to different plugin directories? If yes, then this is the problem.

I modeled your approach and ran the some tests to prove what I thought. The code is effectively the same as yours and reads plugins from the subdirectories of bin/plugin directory of the server.

Simple test using NUnit to exercise the server class library:

```
[Test]
public void Compose()
{
    var server = new Server();
    server.Compose();
    Console.WriteLine("Plugins found: " + server.FASTAdapters.Count());
    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach (var adapter in server.FASTAdapters)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(adapter.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine(adapter.GetType().Assembly.FullName);
        Console.WriteLine(adapter.GetType().Assembly.CodeBase);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Assert.Pass();
}
```

Test results for one plugin in place:

```
Plugins found: 1

AdapterPlugin.ControllerAdapter
AdapterPlugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
file:///C:/USERS/GARKIN/DOCUMENTS/VISUAL STUDIO 2012/PROJECTS/MEFADAPTERS/ADAPTERSERVER/BIN/DEBUG/PLUGINS/ADAPTER1/ADAPTERPLUGIN.DLL
```

Test result for two plugins in place, using the same plugin assembly copied over to two distinct plugin directories (probably your case):

```
Plugins found: 2

AdapterPlugin.ControllerAdapter
AdapterPlugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
file:///C:/USERS/GARKIN/DOCUMENTS/VISUAL STUDIO 2012/PROJECTS/MEFADAPTERS/ADAPTERSERVER/BIN/DEBUG/PLUGINS/ADAPTER1/ADAPTERPLUGIN.DLL

AdapterPlugin.ControllerAdapter
AdapterPlugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
file:///C:/USERS/GARKIN/DOCUMENTS/VISUAL STUDIO 2012/PROJECTS/MEFADAPTERS/ADAPTERSERVER/BIN/DEBUG/PLUGINS/ADAPTER1/ADAPTERPLUGIN.DLL
```

You also get the exact same result if you give distinct names to those DLLs because effectively it is still the same assembly inside.

Now I add the third plugin, but this time it is a different plugin assembly:

```
Plugins found: 3

AdapterPlugin.ControllerAdapter
AdapterPlugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
file:///C:/USERS/GARKIN/DOCUMENTS/VISUAL STUDIO 2012/PROJECTS/MEFADAPTERS/ADAPTERSERVER/BIN/DEBUG/PLUGINS/ADAPTER1/ADAPTERPLUGIN.DLL

AdapterPlugin.ControllerAdapter
AdapterPlugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
file:///C:/USERS/GARKIN/DOCUMENTS/VISUAL STUDIO 2012/PROJECTS/MEFADAPTERS/ADAPTERSERVER/BIN/DEBUG/PLUGINS/ADAPTER1/ADAPTERPLUGIN.DLL

AdapterPlugin2.ControllerAdapter
AdapterPlugin2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
file:///C:/USERS/GARKIN/DOCUMENTS/VISUAL STUDIO 2012/PROJECTS/MEFADAPTERS/ADAPTERSERVER/BIN/DEBUG/PLUGINS/ADAPTER3/ADAPTERPLUGIN2.DLL
```

The different assembly is of course found and identified correctly.

So this all boils down to how the .NET runtime handles assembly loading, which is a complex and strictly defined process and works differently for strongly and weakly named assemblies. I recommend this article for a good explanation of the process: [Assembly Load Contexts Subtleties](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2007/03/06/Assembly-Load-Contexts-Subtleties.aspx).

In this case, the same process is followed behind the scenes when using MEF:

1. The .NET runtime finds the first weakly typed plugin assembly and loads it from that location and MEF does it's export processing.
2. Then MEF tries to process the next plugin assembly it founds using the catalog, but the runtime sees the assembly with the same metadata already loaded. So it uses the already loaded one to look for exports and ends up instantiating the same type again. It does not touch the second DLL at all.

There is no way the same assembly can be loaded more than once by the runtime. Which makes perfect sense when you think of it. Assembly is just bunch of types with their metadata and once loaded the types are available, no need to load them again.

This may not be completely correct, but I hope it helps to explain where the problem lies and it should be clear that duplicating DLLs for this purpose is useless.

Now regarding what you want to achieve. It seems that all you need is just to get multiple instances of the SAME adapter plugin to use them for different purposes, which has nothing to do with multiplying DLLs.

To get multiple adapter instances you can define multiple imports with `RequiredCreationPolicy` set to `CreationPolicy.NonShared` in your server which MEF will accordingly instantiate for you:

```
public class Server
{
    [Import(RequiredCreationPolicy = CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    public IFASTAdapter FirstAdapter { get; set; }

    [Import(RequiredCreationPolicy = CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    public IFASTAdapter SecondAdapter { get; set; }

    // Other adapters ...

    public void Compose()
    {
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        var pluginsDir = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "plugins");
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(pluginsDir))
        {
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(d));
        }
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);
    }
}
```

Corresponding NUnit test to check that the adapters are instantiated and that they are different instances:

```
[Test]
public void Compose_MultipleAdapters_NonShared()
{
    var server = new Server();
    server.Compose();
    Assert.That(server.FirstAdapter, Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.That(server.SecondAdapter, Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.That(server.FirstAdapter, Is.Not.SameAs(server.SecondAdapter));
}
```

If all of this will help you to some extent, we can also take look at how you want to configure what and how to instantiate using the app.config.

Comment: Good answer. This is the way to go, use PartCreationPolicy NonShared and import instances of IFASTAdapter where needed.

Comment: Great, this is giving me a lot of insight in how the assembly loading and MEF is working. Thanks for your answer! I see now that my approach of creating six separate assemblies, which all implement the same interface and baseclass, is not necessary. For the current release, I leave it the way it is now. But I will definitely try your approach with CreationPolicy.NonShared. I am curious how to instantiate the various instances using the app.config, can you give me some more information on that?

Comment: @Cornelis Sorry for the late reply, I was quite busy past week. Regarding the app.config usage, do you want to be able to configure the imports themselves by the config file (i.e. what should be imported) or only to configure the parameters for the specific plugin instances, imported the way I described? These are two quite different requirements. Also MEF is not configurable by the config files out of the box, it only comes with the attributed programming model.

Comment: @famousgarkin I think my main concern at this moment is how to efficiently maintain configuration parameters. My project contains a lot of assemblies, which in fact are all loaded in one main program which is a Windows Service. I have noticed that I have to put the configuration settings in a high level app.config, because otherwise they seem not to be found. I already found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89245/how-do-you-manage-net-app-config-files-for-large-applications which is about this problem.

Comment: @famousgarkin In my current setup, with the plugins based on a base AdapterClass and an Interface, there is no need imo for a configuration based loading of plugins. However, when I might switch to your suggested CreationPolicy, I don't see how to differentiate between the plugin assemblies (copied, but with different configsettings). You name FirstAdapter and SecondAdapter in the composing class, but how can I specify those classes in the plugins?

Comment: @Cornelis There is one plugin created multiple times for different purposes in the host application. Therefore I think the plugin itself should not need to know about the different configurations it can be used with. The host application should contain configuration for the instances it creates. This can be easily achieved using the app settings in app.config, e.g. using instance name to name the keys, like `<add key="FirstAdapter-Param1" value="1"/>`, and reading it appropriately. Or you can create your own configuration section for this, which is more robust, but a bit more complex solution.

Comment: @famousgarkin Thanks, I will try something in a while. Have to work on another project atm :)